# Applying a style to a specific body class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to apply an additional "margin-top" to a specific class in the body. This class' name is already in a CSS file and reads:

```
html body.admin-menu {
   margin-top:29px !important;
}
```

However, I need a place in my jQuery to change this margin-top to 60px.

I have tried these 4 options with no cigar:

```
$('html body.admin-menu').addClass('marginfix');

$('html body.admin-menu').attr('style', 'margin-top:60px !important');

$('html body.admin-menu').attr('style', function(i,s) { return s + 'margin-top: 60px !important;' });

$('<style>.marginfix { margin-top:60px !important; }</style>').appendTo('html body.admin-menu');
```

The only element I can seem to affect is "html" but I need to apply this style to this very specific case (html body.admin-menu), and not just the "html" tag.

Anyone know what will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but what seems to me is that you are missing the doc ready method. It seems that you are adding the class to the element before it is ready.

This should work:

```
$(function(){
    $('html body.admin-menu').addClass('marginfix');
});
```

or try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('html body.admin-menu').css({marginTop: '60px'});
}); // above code will make a inline css to the body.
```

try to wrap it in doc ready method and i guess you have style for this css class `.marginfix` in your css file somewhere. Although you can omit the `html` from the selector.

this css should be available like this:

```
html body.admin-menu {
   margin-top:29px !important;
}

.marginfix{
    margin-top:60px !important; // this overrides above class applied to body.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I apologize, it actually is adding the class, (no errors in console) but the margin-top is not applying to the body. padding-top works, but any idea why this might be?

Comment: i hope this class name is having `!important` css hack and that should be available there in the css file below this css class `body.admin-menu`.

Comment: It seems as though "margintop" in the CSS does nothing to the body. However, I instead used relative positioning & top:60px; with a custom style (in your first option) to get it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body.admin-menu').css({'margin-top':'60px'});
```

and remove that `!important` from your CSS. Just add the `body.admin-menu` section after all other CSS so it overrides any previous styles.

Comment: Because .admin-menu is a class only identified when there is a logged in admin.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however, this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that to add the style to your `<head>`

```
$('<style type="text/css">.marginfix { margin-top:60px !important; }</style>').appendTo($('head'));
```

You then call your `addClass()` methods:

```
$('body.admin-menu').addClass('marginfix');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, this doesn't seem to be working.